# Syntax error on SHOW TABLES LIKE

Tags: mysql, php-5.5

I don't understand why is it saying `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''User_notifications''` on this query:

```
<?php
include 'constants.php';
$username=$_POST['username'];
$notiftable=$username.'_notifications';
$con=new mysqli('',databaseuser,databasepassword,database);
if($con)
{
    $q="SHOW TABLES LIKE '$notiftable'";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your table name `User_notifications` is getting double-escaped (i.e. it is being escaped twice).  This is most likely happening because the PHP function is escaping it already, and you are doing it a second time.  Try not escaping the table name yourself, i.e.:

```
 $q = "SHOW TABLES LIKE $notiftable";
```

Comment: Nevermind, the error was coming from another query. I'm a noob.

Comment: @Alexiy So are you saying that `''User_notifications''` was never causing a  problem?

Comment: Actually, it does cause an error if `User_notifications` is not put in quotes.